# How to access object graph in javers

Tags: javers

I have two entities Employee and Address.

Employee.java

```
public class Employee {

private Long id;
private String firstName;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}    

}
```

Address.java

```
public class Address {

public Address(Long addressId, String address, Long id) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
    this.address = address;
    this.id = id;
}

public Address() {

}

@Id
private Long addressId;
private Long employeeId;
private String address;

public Long getAddressId() {
    return addressId;
}
public void setAddressId(Long addressId) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
}
public Long getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}
public void setEmployeeId(Long employeeId) {
    this.employeeId= employeeId;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

}

Useing Javers api i want all the changes made by Employee including Address.

suppose employeeId e1 with name e made some change in address a1 with address xyz and employeeId e1

```
Changes changes = javers.findChanges(QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(id,com.mybatis.emo.bean.Employee.class).withNewObjectChanges(true).build());
```

I want address changes also comes while querying employee.

Comment: I don't understand your issue: "...address changes also comes while querying employee...", can you specified "... also comes..." ? Do you want to get the address (use `getAddress()`), or do you want to be able to change the address (use `setAddress(String)`)?

Comment: @dboy when i call findChange method of javers on employee it should return both employee and address as well.